# What does "given" mean in this sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

The sentence is:

> In a statement that had surreal qualities given the surging prices in
> recent weeks, the group, which includes Russia, said that current
> fundamentals and the outlook for the future pointed “to a
> well-balanced market.”

Does is mean that the **statement** which had surreal qualities is making prices move up and down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it means that the person reporting the statement finds it incredible.

That person does not believe that the outlook for the market can be described as well-balanced, given the rapid rise in prices.

The comment refers only to the statement and not to any effect that it might have on the market.

Answer (score 2):

'Given' can be used to refer to something we already know.

> In a statement that had surreal qualities because of the surging
> prices...

The writer feels that the statement is surreal because of what we know about the surging prices.

> given
>
> preposition
>
> knowing about or considering a particular thing
>
> *Given his age, he's a remarkably fast runner.
>
> Given (the fact) that he's had six months to do this, he hasn't made
> much progress.*

[Given (Cambridge Dictiionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/given)